# How to install native base in expo project?

Tags: react-native, expo, native-base

I tried many ways to install native base in expo project

I was thinking this command will work

```
$ npm install native-base --save
```

but I can install native base in react native with this command

Comment: You should give more details about the problem you are having.

Comment: you can follow the Setup with CRNA in [NativeBase docs](https://docs.nativebase.io/docs/GetStarted.html). This may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you follow the [quick start](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#getting-started) here
you have to follow [Setup with CRNA steps](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase#4-getting-started) to create React Native project using the CRNA cli.
I think you missing Install @expo/vector-icons step here.

Answer (score -1):

I've created native-base working with expo environment named "expo-base".
You can check this out from here :-)
https://github.com/Dibyasundar444/expo-base